# Todo to span multiple paragraphs

Tags: macros

I can define a todo command like this:

```latex
\newcommand\todo[1]{\textcolor{red}{TODO: #1}}
```

This command does not work for multiple paragraphs with line breaks in between:

```latex
\todo{hello
world}
```

How can I create such a command that would work on multiple paragraphs?

I am aware of the `todonotes` package, but would like to know if it's possible with the `\newcommand` macro.

Comment: The limitation here is your use of `\textcolor{color}{text}`, it does not support more than one paragraph  You can instead use `\newcommand\todo[1]{{\color{red}TODO: #1}}`, but I'd go for todonotes or fixme (I use the latter in a modified form that looks like the former)

Comment: Ah, thanks! What an easy fix!

Answer (score 1):

As @daleif has said in comments, the problem is that `\textcolor` does not allow `\par` in its argument.
Internally, the macro is defined as:

```
\def\textcolor#1#{\@textcolor{#1}}
\def\@textcolor#1#2#3{\protect\leavevmode{\color#1{#2}#3}}
```

If `\@textcolor` would have been defined as `\long`, you should not have this problem.
So you could, in principle redefine this macro, but @daleif´s solution is much more convenient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{red}{TODO: #1}}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@textcolor#1#2#3{\protect\leavevmode{\color#1{#2}#3}}
\makeatother

\todo{Hello 

 world}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The limitation here is the use of `\textcolor{color}{text}` it can only handle up to a single paragraphs worth of text. Simpler method:

```
\newcommand\todo[1]{{\color{red}TODO: }}
```

Here the extra `{}` acts as a group such that the color does not escape.

I would though, take a look at todonotes or fixme instead of doing too many homemade solutions. Fixme can be configured to print the text in the margin in such a way that you can use `\fxnote` practically everywhere. Since todonotes use `\marginpar` (at least it did the last time I looked) it has several limitations on where it can be used. Both can also make a list of all the notes in the document
'